# Finding angle between two hyperplanes given basis vectors

Tags: euclidean-geometry, angle, multilinear-algebra

There is a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. In it there live two hyperplanes of dimension $m$ each. Both hyperplanes pass through the origin $\vec{0}$. The hyperplanes are defined by the corresponding orthonormal basis vector sets $\{\vec{a}_i\}$ and $\{\vec{b}_i\}$ where $i \in \{1, 2, ..., m\}$. What is the expression for the angle between the two hyperplanes? If it is not possible to express their relationship with just one angle, how many angles are necessary, and how to compute those?

Comment: I think that you could assign the angle for hyperplanes of dimension $n-1$.

Comment: @Widawensen I have thought about this for a bit, but I am not sure the restriction holds if the hyperplanes are known to pass through the origin. For example, I can easily construct a single angle between two lines in 3D when they pass through the origin

Comment: Yes, we can assign the angle between lines when they pass through origin ( they form a plane)  Moreover we can assign the angle between a line and some dim. $m-1$ hyperplane. In this case the angle is defined as the angle between the line and the line orthoghonally projected  onto the hyperplane.

Comment: @Widawensen so would you say that a single angle cannot be constructed between, e.g., two 2D planes in 4D space?

Comment: I don't know a procedure, .. the angle has a meaning only between two vectors (via dot product) hence we should have unique vectors for these 2D and 4D spaces, but ... how to construct them?